# Spring Boot: how to use FilteringMessageListenerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application which listens to messages on a Kafka queue. To filter those messages, have the following two classs

```
@Component
public class Listener implements MessageListener {
    private final CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic.boot}")
    public void onMessage(Object o) {
        System.out.println("LISTENER received payload *****");
        this.latch1.countDown();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Listener listener;

    @Bean
    public FilteringMessageListenerAdapter filteringReceiver() {
        return new FilteringMessageListenerAdapter(listener, recordFilterStrategy() );
    }

    public RecordFilterStrategy recordFilterStrategy() {
        return  new RecordFilterStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord) {
                System.out.println("IN FILTER");
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

While messages are being processed by the `Listener` class, the `RecordFilterStrategy` implementation is not being invoked. What is the correct way to use `FilteringMessageListenerAdapter`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The solution was as follows:
No need for the `FilteringMessageListenerAdapter` class.

Rather, create a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`, rather than relying on what Spring Boot provides out of the box. Then, set the `RecordFilterStrategy` implementation on this class.

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String>
kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(recordFilterStrategy());
    return factory;
}
```